# Add onclick event into the image when insertEmbed Quill editor

Tags: javascript, quill

I have inserted the image into the Quill editor by this code:

```
const index = self._quillInstance.getSelection();
self._quillInstance.insertEmbed(index.index, 'image', img.src);
```

How can I insert the onclick event into the image tag have been embed?

Comment: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1055 this work for me